# Can't connect to samba using openVPN

Tags: vpn, samba, openvpn, smb-conf

I'm fairly new to using VPN. 
For a home project I'm running a OpenVPN server. 
This server runs within a network 192.168.2.0 and subnet 255.255.255.0

I can connect to this net work using the ip range 5.5.0.0 I guess the subnet is 255.255.255.192, but I'm not really sure about that.

When connecting to my VPN network I can access the server via 5.5.0.1 and I can see the samba shares created on that machine. However I'm not allowed to connect to the samba share. When I look at the samba log of the computer which tries to connect I can see these messages:

```
lib/access.c:338(allow_access) Denied connection from 5.5.0.132 (5.5.0.132)
```

These are the share definition in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
interfaces = 192.168.2.0/32 5.5.0.0/24
security = user

#   wins-support = no
#   wins-server = w.x.y.z.
// A LOT OF MORE SETTINGS AND COMMENTS

hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.2.0/24 5.5.0.132/24
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
browseable = yes
path = [path to share]
directory mask = 0755
force create mode = 0755
valid users = [a valid user, which i use to login with]
writeable = yes
force group = [the group i force to write with]
force user = [the user i force to write with]
```

This is the output of the ifconfig command

```
as0t0     
    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    inet addr:5.5.0.1  P-t-P:5.5.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.192
    UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t1     
    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    inet addr:5.5.0.65  P-t-P:5.5.0.65  Mask:255.255.255.192
    UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

as0t2     
    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    inet addr:5.5.0.129  P-t-P:5.5.0.129  Mask:255.255.255.192
    UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:xxxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:xxxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
    RX bytes:xxxx (xxxx MB)  TX bytes:12403514 (xxxx MB)

as0t3     
    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    inet addr:5.5.0.193  P-t-P:5.5.0.193  Mask:255.255.255.192
    UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:7041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:9797 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
    RX bytes:xxxx (xxxx KB)  TX bytes:xxxx (xxxx MB)

eth1      
    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:2e:61:78:21
    inet addr:192.168.2.100  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:7821/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:xxxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:xxxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:xxxx (xxxx MB)  TX bytes:xxxx (xxxx MB)
    Interrupt:16 Base address:0x6000

lo
    Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
    RX packets:xxxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:xxxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:xxxx (xxxx MB)  TX bytes:xxxx (xxxx MB)
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

My server is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Why are you using 5.5.0.0/24 internally?

Comment: Thats a good question ;-). I did this, because the tutorial said so....

Comment: Don't. That isn't your IP range and they're not reserved. Now might be a good time to read [RFC1918](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918).

Comment: I would change VPN subnet to `10.0.0.0/24` since it is part RFC1918. The IP address 5.5.0.1 belong to a German ISP.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to add /24 for single hosts. you could try

```
hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.2.0/24 5.5.0.0/24
```

to allow all hosts from the ips 5.5.0.0 - 5.5.0.255 or if you jsut want a single host try

```
hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.2.0/24 5.5.0.132
```

for a host with the ip 5.5.0.132

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution you provided did not work. As a matter a fact, I already tried that one earlier.